# Div overlay hue issue only in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Please visit http://www.in2medical.com/ with IE8.
There seems to be some sort of lighter hue over the dark blue bar (in which the logo resides) on top. This hue is not visible in IE9, chrome or firefox..
It looks like in IE8 the div in which I place the content and I position on top of the background is automatically changing the color of the div over which it lays.
How is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save `/images/bg_logobar.png` without the [embedded colour profile](http://www.gballard.net/psd/save_for_web_embed_ICC_profile.html).

[image]

I did it for you, but you need to learn how to fix it yourself or you'll have the same problem again.

Comment: Great! Found out how to do this in PS too, so did the other images directly. Thanks!